# How to give a color for the placeholder in <mat-select>?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm not using the mat-form-field before mat-select. I want to give some color to the placeholder. Please help me. Thank you.

```
<mat-select class="dropBox" placeholder="Select One" (selectionChange)="mymethod($event.value)" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of myList" [value]="initOption">
                             {{option}}
                     </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, to color the placeholder red, add this in your component's stylesheet:

```
::ng-deep .dropBox .mat-select-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can you tell me how to reset the mat-select in the above code? Like is there any method to reset the drop down so that it displays the placeholder every time after some action?

Comment: You are welcome. What do you mean by reset?

Comment: For example, let's assume there is another select . So let's say I choose an option in the first picker. Then I choose an option in the second picker. Then when I change an option in the first picker, the second one should show the placeholder. I want to know how to do this functionality

Comment: Add `[(ngModel)]="selectedOption"` to the second select, and a property `selectedOption: string;` in the component class. Then in the first select, add `(selectionChange)="resetSecondSelect()`. Finally add a method `resetSecondSelect() { this.selectedOption = ""; }`

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Benny, I don't know how to wrap the text in mat options.Because if the text is too long then  part of the text is not visible in the option. Can you show how to wrap the text in the options

Comment: @vishnu please share your code in Stackblitz to show me exactly what kind of help you seek